# Saving a csv with current date and time

Tags: python

I am running some code and I would like to save a csv file which include the current date and time in its name.
For example: I run some code now (`12:24, Jan 15`) and I would like to have something like

```
name_1224_01152021.csv
```

Can you tell me how to print/save this information, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code according to your question :

```
from datetime import datetime

filename = datetime.now().strftime('filename_%H%M_%m%d%Y.csv')

with open(filename, "w+") as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow(["row1", "row2"])
```

in filename you have to write your file name the output of this will be shown as

```
filename_0620_01152021_.csv
```

Answer (score 7):

The following code should format the name as per your requirement:

```
import datetime
name = f'name_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M_%m%d%Y")}.csv'
print(name)
# prints 'name_0628_01152021.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you want :

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
# dd/mm/YY
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

fname = "name_1224" + d1 + ".csv"
#fname = "name_1224" + str(d1) + ".csv"
```

Comment: thehand0, unfortunately 1224 is not a name, but it is time information.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Realised that afterwards. Md Johirul Islam's answer is better. Use that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

val_time =datetime.time.now()

now you can append name and val_time and save file with that name

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date with `strftime`.

```
import datetime

filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('name_%H%_%d%m%Y.csv')
```

then you can do something like

```
open(filename, "w").write("blahblah")
```